# Do you have a good application example of Approximate Dynamic Programming?

Tags: programming, dynamic

Have you ever tackled a finance problem with Approximate Dynamic Programming?

I have only used dynamic programming for simple examples like a optimal extraction in mining.

- Do you have canonical reading material that you recommend?
- Do you have any code implementation example (in any language or pseudo code)?

Comment: Hi donpresente, welcome to Quant.SE! There is a ton of stuff on Google, without more information it's hard to make a specific recommendation. For applications to finance you can do worse than read the papers and books of Dimitri P. Bertsekas et. al.

Comment: Hello Bob. Sorry for being vague. I just wanted to know if someone of the users used in the past ADP for any questions in finance that they wanted to answer. Like for example, trading strategies. Thanks!

Comment: Well not professionally but I used it for my thesis in a portfolio allocation context. I have some literature to share although it's not the most recent stuff. It can give you a good start.

Comment: @BobJansen sure if you dont mind, that would be great. Best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I totally missed the coining of the term "Approximate Dynamic Programming" as did some others. Also, in my thesis I focused on specific issues (return predictability and mean variance optimality) so this might be far from complete. That's enough disclaiming.

Let's start with an old overview: [Ralf Korn - Optimal Portfolios](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3548). [Kenneth Judd - Numerical Methods in Economics](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/numerical-methods-economics) gave me some good background on approximation of functions. You may not need it.

Brandt, M.W. et al. - "A Simulation Approach to Dynamic Portfolio Choice with an Application to Learning About Return Predictability" does what it says and uses value function approximation to do it. Van Binsbergen, J.H. and Brandt, M.W. - "Solving dynamic portfolio choice problems by recursing on optimized portfolio weights or on the value function?" improve upon this idea. Garlappi, L. and Skoulakis, G. - "Solving Consumption and Portfolio Choice Problems: The State Variable Decompostion Method" provide important numerical improvements.

The literature of [Bertsekas](http://www.athenasc.com/dpbook.html) should be of interest as his papers are often cited. However I haven't looked at them yet.
I hope this interests you, if this is not what you meant, do tell.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great start for me. Thanks for sharing. I will start with Brandt!